# Subset relationships in the product topology

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be spaces, $A \subset X, B \subset Y$, and give $X \times Y$ the product topology. What holds between $A' \times B'$ and $(A \times B)'$?

[image]

Need some help here, I am supposed to show or prove that: A' X B' = (A X B)', where A' and B' are limit points respectively. I showed this to my prof, he told me that it needs a lot of fixtures since the concept of limit points are not clearly established. Below is the note he gave us for limit points and closure of a set. 
[image]

Can someone figure out the issues in my proof and correct it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We go to show that $A'\times B'\subseteq(A\times B)'$.

Let $(x,y)\in A'\times B'$. Let $W$ be an arbitrary open neighborhood
of $(x,y)$. Then there exist open sets $U\subseteq X$ and $V\subseteq Y$
such that $(x,y)\in U\times V\subseteq W$ because $\{U\times V\mid U\subseteq X,Y\subseteq Y\mbox{ are open}\}$
is a base for the product topology of $X\times Y$. In another word,
$U$ and $V$ are open neighborhoods of $x$ and $y$ respectively.
Since $x\in A'$ and $y\in B'$, we have $(U\setminus\{x\})\cap A\neq\emptyset$
and $(V\setminus\{y\})\cap B\neq\emptyset$. Choose $a\in(U\setminus\{x\})\cap A$
and $b\in(V\setminus\{y\})\cap B$. Clearly $(a,b)\in(W\setminus\{(x,y)\})\cap(A\times B)$.
This shows that $(x,y)\in(A\times B)$'.

In general, it is false that $(A\times B)'\subseteq A'\times B'$.
Counter-example: Let $X=Y=\mathbb{\mathbb{R}}$, equipped with the
usual topology. Let $A=\{0\}$ and $B=\mathbb{R}$. Clearly $A'=\emptyset$
and hence $A'\times B'=\emptyset$. We go to show that $\{0\}\times\mathbb{R}\subseteq(A\times B)'$.
Let $b\in\mathbb{R}$ and let $W$ be an open neighborhood of $(0,b)$.
Choose open subsets $U$ and $V$ such that $(0,b)\in U\times V\subseteq W$.
Choose $b'\in V$ with $b'\neq b$. (Clearly
$V\neq\{b\}$ because $\mathbb{R}$ is equipped with the usual topology.)
Now $(0,b')\in U\times V$ and $(0,b')\neq(0,b)$. It follows that
$[W\setminus\{(0,b)\}]\cap(A\times B)\neq\emptyset$. This shows that
$(0,b)\in(A\times B)'$ for any $b\in\mathbb{R}$.